# How To Insert Data And Files , Images To Database And Folder In Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have created a registration form. I want to insert data to a database and files, images to folders. When I insert data and file or image, it's successfully inserted. But when I try without a file or image, it gives me this error:

> (2/2) QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'fileimg' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `academic` (`name`, `username`, `pw`)
>   values (Kisalka Rajapaksha, 960863801V,
>   $2y$10$u0Ryg3Yi9wYma.wm5piP2.1HFHKxruo6gZDU2Fo1onwQJhJmOWhG.))

How can I fix this?

> Controller.php file.

```
function insert(Request $req)
    {

        $this->validate($req, [
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);


        if(Input::hasFile('file_img')){

            $name = $req->input('name');
            $username = $req->input('username');
            $password = $req->input('password');
            $passen = bcrypt($password);
            $file = Input::file('file_img');
            $fileimg = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = 'img';

        $rules = array(
            'file_img' => 'required|max:10000|mimes:doc,docx,jpeg,png,jpg'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            // redirect our user back with error messages
            $messages = $validator->messages();
            // send back to the page with the input data and errors
            return Redirect::to('RegShort')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
            return redirect('RegShort');

        }

        else if ($validator->passes()) {  

        $filemove = $file->move($destinationPath, $fileimg);

        $dataimg = array("name"=>$name,"username"=>$username,"pw"=>$passen,"fileimg"=>$fileimg,"filemove"=>$filemove);

        DB::table('academic')->insert($dataimg);

        $req->session()->flash('Msg', 'Successfully Inserted !!');

        return redirect('RegShort');

        }
        }

        else
        {
            $names = $req->input('name');
            $usernames = $req->input('username');
            $passwords = $req->input('password');
            $passens = bcrypt($passwords);

            $data = array("name"=>$names,"username"=>$usernames,"pw"=>$passens);

            DB::table('academic')->insert($data);

            $req->session()->flash('Msg', 'Successfully Inserted !!');

            return redirect('RegShort');
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set UNIQUE or NOT NULL for `fileimg` column.
You should allow NULL for column
Try this: `ALTER TABLE academic MODIFY fileimg VARCHAR(255);`

Comment: It's 100% Perfectly Worked !! Thank U Very Much Bro !! :D

Answer (score 2):

You should set the fileimg as a nullable field on the migration file.

```
$table->string('fileimg')->nullable();
```

That way you can save entries with no fileimg.

Comment: Thank U Very Much Bro !! :D